# How to tweet a video with hashtags and emoji using Oauth1?

Tags: c#, restsharp, tweets, oauth-1.0a, twitter-api-v1

Trying to post a tweet with video in hindi language with hashtags and emoji using v1.1 update.json endpoint of twitter api. Video has been uploaded successfully media id is generated against it and video is ready to be posted, but when I am posting it using RestSharp(v 106.11.7), I am getting a success message with relevant metadata of tweet. But on twitter tweet does not have a video attached to it, Only the text is posted in the tweet. Not sure wether the encoding is wrong or it has something to do with restsharp because when I tried via postman the video is posted correctly with  tweet text.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com" + "/" + v1.1 + "/" + "statuses/update.json")
{
    Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(config.ConsumerKey, config.ConsumerSecret, config.Token, config.TokenSecret)
};
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest( RestSharp.Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("status", content);
request.AddParameter("media_ids", String.Join(",", mediaIds));

request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = Regex.IsMatch(content, "([^\\x00-\\x7F]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

var queryResult = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

What need to be corrected to tweet a proper video with hindi text and hashtags.